# Silverlight - is a DependencyProperty required in this situation?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have a Silverlight 4 application which uses the MVVM pattern.  I have:
1. A standard View
2. A standard ViewModel
3. A separate UserControl which essentially is a wrapper around a DataGrid.

I have placed the UserControl on to my View whose DataContext is the ViewModel.  The ViewModel has a property which contains information required by the UserControl (configuration details for the grid).  I wish to create "something" within the UserControl so I can bind to the property on the ViewModel and when this property changes the UserControl can reconfigure itself as required.

Is this something a "DependencyProperty"?

RESOLUTION:

I took sternr's advice and implemented a DependencyProperty within the UserControl in order to bind to a property on the ViewModel.  I used a Visual Studio snippet from the following link to help code the property: http://wildermuth.com/2009/03/09/Silverlight_Dependency_Property_Snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the `PropertyName="{Binding}"` mechanism, you have to use a DependencyProperty.
However, if you only what to enable other resources to subscribe to changes over one of your properties, it is sufficient to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface